# Issue in display flex with text

Tags: html, css

I have a header where on the left side there is header name and on the right side, there are a few buttons.
And the problem is, header name splits into two lines at last white space.
I have below code and it's happening because of `.right` class's width set to inherit.
pls refer the code.
Is there any way for not letting the text to split?

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <!---->
  <h6>A B C D E</h6>
  <div class="right">
    buttons
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gr9m27n4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the code by assigning `flex-grow: 1` to the `h6` (the header name). This will have ensure the text grows to fill the most available space in the row. The remaining space will be implicitly given to `.right` (buttons).

```css
/* default styles */
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;  
}

.parent h6 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h6>A B C D E</h6>
  <div class="right">
    buttons
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8o0axfm/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`justify-content: space-between`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#Values) to evenly distribute your two items within the parent container like so:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h6>A B C D E</h6>
  <div class="right">
    buttons
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex-shrink` property to achieve what you wanted. I have remove `width:inherit`  and used `flex-grow` property. I assume that would be better in this case.

> **flex-grow** defines the ability for a flex item to grow if necessary. It accepts a unitless value that serves as a proportion. It dictates what amount of the available space inside the flex container the item should take up.
>
> If all items have flex-grow set to 1, the remaining space in the container will be distributed equally to all children. If one of the children has a value of 2, the remaining space would take up twice as much space as the others (or it will try to, at least).

```css
.parent {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

h6 {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <!---->
  <h6>A B C D E</h6>
  <div class="right">
    buttons
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove   `width: inherit` from  `right` class and add `margin-left:auto` to align it to the right